# counting the times a character appears in string java using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I'm doing some recursion exercises and one has quite confused me. The problem stated that I should count the times "yo" has appeared in a string, but if the letter 'o' appears before the "yo", I'm not supposed to count it.

"yoyo" is counted as two, but "yooyo" is counted as one. I have done a code but it doesn't follow the condition of not counting the "yo" that has an 'o' before it. Thanks for the help!

My code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Mp3
{
    static int oui(String arr, int index)
    {
      int count = 0;
      if(index >= arr.length())
        return 0;
  
      if(count == 0)
      {
        if(arr.charAt(index) == 'y')
        {
          if(arr.charAt(index + 1) == 'o')
            count++;
          else if(arr.charAt(index - 1) == 'o' && arr.charAt(index - 2) != 'y')
            --count;
          else
            return count + oui(arr, index + 1);
        }
     }
     return count + oui(arr, index + 1);
  }

  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
     String inp3 = "yoyooyoxhadjiohioyooyoyoxxyoyo";

     int res3 = oui(inp3, 0);

     System.out.println(inp3 + ":" + res3);
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "but 'yooyo' is not accepted"? Your method is not supposed to accept or reject strings, is it? It is supposed to _count_ things. How many `yo`s should it count in `yooyo`?

Comment: What about `oyoyo`? Should that last `yo` be counted?

Comment: It should according to his question @Sweeper

Comment: the "yo" counted in "yooyo" is only one (the first yo is the only one counted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Mp3
{
  static int oui(String arr, int index)
  {
    int count = 0;
    if(index >= arr.length())
      return 0;
    if(arr.charAt(index)=='o' && arr.charAt(index+1)=='y'&&arr.charAt(index+2)=='o') 
      
       return count + oui(arr, index + 3);
      

    if(arr.charAt(index) == 'y' && arr.charAt(index + 1) == 'o')
       
       return count+ 1 +oui(arr, index + 2);
     
    
    return count + oui(arr, index + 1);
 }


  public static void main (String[] args)
 {
  String inp3 = "yoyooyoxhadjiohioyooyoyoxxyoyo";

  int res3 = oui(inp3, 0);

  System.out.println(inp3 + ":" + res3);
 }
```

}

**I tried not to change a lot from your code :

1. I check if index= o then if followed by yo I skip them and check afterward
2. I check if index= y and followed by o then I take them and check afterwards cause I always check for o first
3. Simple :) If you have any questions post a comment and I will try to explain better**

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation! I understand them better now. Thanks again!

Comment: @PoohSan You're more than welcome I'm glad I helped :)!

Answer (score 0):

Make this simple:

### Algo

let's assume `index` represents 0-th index initially.

1. check the `index`-ed and `index+1`-ed character , if it is `y` and `o` increment `count` by +1 and `index`-ed value by +2;
2. if it is not, simply ignore the `count` and increment `index`-ed value by +1.
3. do it repetitively until you reach at the end of the string.

### Code

```
caller :: getCountYo("yoyooyoxhadjiohioyooyoyoxxyoyo", 0);

private int getCountYo(String input, int index) {
    int count = 0;
    /* when you reach at the end of the string */
    if(index == input.length() || index+1 == input.length()) {
        return 0;
    }else {
        /* when "yo" found as a sub-string */
        if(input.charAt(index) == 'y' && input.charAt(index+1) == 'o') {
            count += getCountYo(input, index+2)+1;
        }else if(input.charAt(index) != 'y') {
            count += getCountYo(input, index+1);
        }
    }
    return count;
   }
```